# Jenkins Shared Library delegation error

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkins [shared library](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/) with the following file:

#### vars/testlib.groovy

```
def foo() {
    echo 'foo'
}

def bar(body) {
    body.delegate = [:]
    body.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
    body()
}
```

And a Pipeline script as follows:

#### Jenkinsfile

```
library 'testlib@master'

testlib.foo()
testlib.bar {
    testlib.foo()
}
```

I get the following output:

```
[Pipeline] echo
foo
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method foo() on null object
```

For some reason, the closure being passed to `testlib.bar` doesn't see `testlib` anymore. This only happens if the resolution strategy favors the delegate; if I use `OWNER_ONLY` or `OWNER_FIRST` it works. It also works if I provide `testlib` in the delegate, either by setting it in the map or by just setting `body.delegate = body.owner`, and it works if I avoid the resolution by just referring to `owner.testlib.foo` in the closure. Furthermore, this only happens with library code; if I just make a test class in the Jenkinsfile it works fine.

It seems as though if the resolution strategy is to check the delegate, and the delegate doesn't provide that property, it immediately fails without bothering to check the owner next. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I have noticed in general that var files with functions gets you into some dark corners (unexplainable and erroneous behavior) with Jenkins pipelines as well as their unit testing. I too had to solve some of these issues using an explicit `this` reference (which is same as `owner` but `this.foo()` looks cleaner than `owner.foo()`).

Answer (score 1):

I can't explain exactly what is going on with the Groovy closure delegation in the Jenkins pipeline but I had a similar problem and I fixed it like this:

**vars/foo.groovy:**

```
def call() {
    echo 'foo'
}
```

**vars/bar.groovy:**

```
//
// Something like:
//
// bar {
//    script = {
//        foo()
//        return 'Called foo'
//    }
// }
//
def call(body) {
    def config = [:]
    body.delegate = config
    body.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
    body()

    // In the bar DSL element
    echo 'I am bar'

    // Expecting a script element as a closure. The insanceof needs script approvals
    //assert config.script != null, 'A script element was not supplied'
    //assert config.script instanceof Closure, 'The script element supplied must be a closure'

    // Call the script closure
    config.script.delegate = this
    config.script.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
    def result = config.script.call()

    // Returning the script result
    return result
}
```

**Jenkinsfile:**

```
library 'testlib@master'

def result = bar {

    script = {

        foo()

        return 'Called foo'
    }

}

echo "result from bar: ${result}"
```

**Jenkins output:**

```
[Pipeline] echo
I am bar
[Pipeline] echo
foo
[Pipeline] echo
result from bar: Called foo
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Just consider the 'bar' DSL closure body passed as some configuration being passed in the form of some assignments like "x = y". So make one of these a closure element that is executed by the implementation of bar() and then you can call other library elements that are defined. I have the code for this example on my Github: https://github.com/macg33zr/jenkins-pipeline-experiments. You might also want to try unit testing outside of Jenkins - I have an example here using a library JenkinsPipelineUnit: https://github.com/macg33zr/pipelineUnit. I recommend this unit test approach if doing some complex work in pipeline as it will preserve your sanity!